# Math help for pseudo 3D in HTML

Tags: html, css, math, 3d

I would like to achieve something very similar to: http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/css-coke.html

However, my cylinder is much fatter and wider than the coke can, I have had a good look through the CSS used to achieve the 3D effect, and it seems that the background-position offsets were manually entered to achieve the desired effect.

It works by offsetting the backgrounds of the smaller paragraph tags (to the outer sides of the can) by larger amounts, but the offsets get smaller as they move towards the middle.

With my cylinder having a much wider body (and more paragraph tags), I figured that there would be some 'proper' calculations that could be done rather than manually playing with the numbers.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to properly calculate the background offsets as they move towards the edge of the cylinder?

**EDIT:** CSS3 3D transforms are not on the cards, hence the desire to replicate the coke example

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp on 3D transforms.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that CSS3 3D transforms are not on the cards, hence the desire to replicate the coke example

Comment: However, take a look on http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: I just told you I cant use this

Comment: Are you looking for the actual mathematical equations to rotate a cylinder, or just API calls to a math library?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a projection from the cylinder to the plane. Since the y dimension is uniform, we are only concerned about calculating the x dimension.

You need to get, for a given x, what is the x coordinate of the background, that wraps around a circle. if **r** is the radius or the circle, for an angle **a**,the x coordinate of the projection, is **r cos(a)**. And the coordinate of the background is **r a** if a is expressed in radians. This means that for the x coordinate (in the plane) the coordinate of the background is **acos (x/r)**.

The datum that you need to set correctly the background for a given **x** is the offset, and so **acos(x/r)-x**.

Now, in a spreadsheet, set all the x values from 0 to r in the a column. In the b column, put the formula **acos(x/r)-x**.

And now, the last step, the optimization: all the rows that have the same value can share the same span, so create a single div for all of them.

Hope that I have succeded explaining this, it's not easy :-)

Comment: This is a great start, thanks vals, I will have a go at the spreadsheet and let you know :)